# 3d object that looks the same from every direction

Tags: three.js

- have a 3d maze with walls and floor.
- have an image with a key ( or other object its not important, but all of em are images and not 3d models ).

I want to display it on the floor and if the camera moves around the object needs to look the same without rotating the object. How can i achieve this?

Update1:

I created a plane geometry added the image ( its a transparent png ) and rotating at render. Its working good, but if i turn the camera sometimes the plane lose transparency for about a few milisec and the get a solid black background ( blinking ).

Any idea why?

here is the code:

```
var texture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('assets/images/sign.png');
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {map: texture, transparent: true} );

plane = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(115, 115,1,1), material );
plane.position.set(500, 0, 1500);
scene.add(plane);

// at render:
plane.rotation.copy( camera.rotation );
```

Comment: just FYI, the technique you describe is known as "billboarding"

Comment: Please do no modify a question and turn it into another question; make a new post instead.

Answer (score 2):

This will be achieved by using:

```
function animate() {
     not3dObject.rotation.z = camera.rotation.z;
     not3dObject.rotation.x = camera.rotation.x;
     not3dObject.rotation.y = camera.rotation.y;
     ...
     render();
}
```

Comment: `not3dObject.rotation.copy( camera.rotation )`

Comment: working good, but sometimes the mesh blinking. explanation at update 1.

Comment: `not3dObject.rotation = camera.rotation;` You can do this, _instead_ of adding to the render loop.